# WooCommerce - Hide product categories where products don't have a specific custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have customized WooCommerce product query to include products which have a specific custom field value e.g external_id = 1234 or production_year = 2017. This works as intended and WooCommerce displays only those products with the correct custom field value.

Next I wanted to hide empty product categories from the product categories widget as I don't want to display empty categories to the users. The product query still uses the custom field values to filter out any unwanted products.

It seemed that the solution was to add

```
$list_args['hide_empty'] = 1;
```

to the woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args filter hook. But sadly the empty product categories are still shown even if they are empty. It seems that the widget doesn't use the same product query to check if the categories have any products. So the widget still shows the categories.

So how can I hide product categories where the product query returns no results?

UPDATE:

Customized query code:

```
public function vehicle_model_query($q)
{
    $id = self::get_current_vehicle_model_id();

    if (isset($id) && !empty($id)) {

        $meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');

        $meta_query[] = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'wcwb_product_vehicle_models',
                'value' => $id
            )
        );

        $q->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code here because above one is used when category has no product assigned,

Comment: @dipmala what code do you mean? The code above is the one I tried to use to hide the categories when no products are found. It does hide categories when no products are assigned but doesn't hide categories when products are assigned but not found with the customized query.

Comment: So you must share your customize query because issue is finding in that one only.

Comment: @dipmala I updated the question with the working code block